# One js file or multiple js file

Tags: javascript

So, let say I have 5 specific pages (Page-1 to Page-5) and 5 different js functions (js-1 to js-5).

In a scenario in which `Page-1` only requires `js-1` and `Page-2` requires `js-2` (and so on), is it better to have one js file which contain all 5 js functions or is it better to have 5 separate js files (each containing js function) which only the corresponding js file is loaded in specific page?

For example, `js-1.js` loaded in `page-1` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say depends on your requirements. I'd do it as you suggested 1 file per 1 page, however, if you in the future plan to use some functions from 1 file on multiple pages (not that unusual), I'd put those in a separate file and then include that file in each page where you require those functions so you wouldn't repeat yourself.

Comment: =) I see. That makes sense. I guess it will be a lot cleaner and easy to understand. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem, I am learning here a lot too. My reasoning is if you use one file for common methods and functions then it is easier to maintain and build on that if you ever need to change something - instead of repairing 3 files you'd have to worry only about one.

Comment: I would add the script inline - saves a few requests ;)

Comment: True make sense. I am currently organizing 100s of lines of js to different page purpose for speedier page load. =) Also, I thought the inline script is not preferred as they do not get cached. is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Each `<script src="file.js"></script>` sends a HTTP request to the server. Assuming there is no caching, each request is a little extra load for the server. For a small number of clients this is not a problem, but when you have a busy site these extra requests can make a difference, affecting the bandwidth per client, and the response time per client. Reducing requests per page has a benefit for busy sites and concatenating javascript files is the best thing to do, even when the resulting file is more than required. There is off course a point where file length overrides the request cost.

For small files concat them. For larger files send as needed. For low use sites it really does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation. It helped =)

Comment: Also, I am trying to research how to cocatenating javascript files. Is it simply combining them into one file?

Comment: @Steve Yes but should be in the same order as the script tags. Not always, but that is the safest.